# Intel Compute Stick STCK1A8LFC Wireless/Bluetooth driver

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth, computestick

hi i am new to Ubuntu , i am using the compute stick with its supported OS Ubuntu 14.04 , but i needed to clean the 8 gb embedded flash drive . so now i cant connect to the net. when i type to terminal about wireless. it says ''no file extensions'' 
i dont know what to do. i found some packages for drivers. but dont know how to install them . just stuck.

UPDATE: I have managed to install 14.04 and on external drive 16.04 and on 16 changed the kernel version to 4.12.0 then used the http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com.tr/2017/06/customizing-ubuntu-isos-documentation.html wi-fi and bluetooth package in the link. then started the network again it is DONE THANKFULLY!!!

Comment: What do you type about wireless?

Comment: i typed at terminal iwconfig

Comment: typed iwconfig and outcome is
lo    no wireless extensions

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? dmesg | grep sdio

Comment: after this command no outcome

Comment: now i am able to install ubuntu 16.04 to same device but of course still no wireless connection. i am wired with my phone and trying to install updates. let's see.

Comment: now updated but still no wireless. trying some but worthles. cant get rfkill list result

Comment: now i am updated to kernel 4.12.0 and wireless network came but it says device is not ready

Comment: it was a 34 hours journey but i have managed to do it :D thanks for veryone !!

Comment: Hey @HakanA., can you answer your own question - do this Q&A?  If you still remember?  I'm in a similar boat...

Answer (score 2):

FYI, Ubuntu 19.04 with its 5.0 kernel now has all the drivers needed for the Intel Compute Stick STCK1A8LFC including Bluetooth and WiFi.

Installation instructions are [here](https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P00004JhY4qSAF/compute-stick-stck1a8lfc-is-running-ubuntu-1904-well?language=en_US).